# Motion of a particle in viscous medium with a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, fluid-dynamics, magnetic-fields, viscosity

While solving this problem that I have mentioned in a post in math stackexchange.I ran into a differential equation not solvable by elementary methods.I just wanted help, to check if my equations are correct.
Here is the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3885811/)  to the post.

Please correct my misunderstanding if there is any.
If possible I would also appreciate any hints to solve the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't how you just got that equation, Maybe you are using polar coordinate but In that case you need two equation one for radial distance and other for angle.One more thing the question in the book can be solve with out use of any differential equation , just by simple argument (I encourge you to solve), But If you want to make a differential equation you can do this.

Suppose a perpendicular magnetic field $\mathbf{B}=-B_0\hat{k}$ in region of motion, then the force equation will be given by
$$m\dot{\mathbf{v}}=-b\mathbf{v}+q(\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}).$$
I'm writing down everything in velocity as all forces are velocity dependent so we just need to solve first order differential equation. Now velocity at any time is $$\mathbf{v}=v_x\hat{i}+v_y\hat{j}$$

$$m(\dot{v_x}\hat{i}+\dot{v_y}\hat{j})=-b(v_x\hat{i}+v_y\hat{j})-qB_0(v_y\hat{i}-v_x\hat{j})$$
So we got a system of equation given by
$$m\dot{v}_x=-bv_x-qB_0v_y$$
$$m\dot{v}_y=-bv_y+qB_0v_x$$

Now that can be solve. But let me make a phase plot to give you visulization.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! I understood how to do it using differential equation but i am very curious as to what are the simple arguments we can use to arrive at the same conclusion,please tell me.

Comment: Yeah, of course, Let me put in a simple way as it's a comment box and so not allowed very long messages. First focus on the direction of forces, the viscous force which always opposite to the velocity and magnetic force which always remain perpendicular to the velocity. If there is no viscous force you would expect circular motion. Now if the switch on the viscous, there will be acceleration which try to pull the particle towards the centre so you would expect the spiral.

Comment: Simple analogy : consider yourself moving in circular path with the help of string which is fixed in one end. So you are going around and around a point. Now viscous is analogous to decrement in the string length so your distance from the centre will decrease continuously and spiral around a center.

Comment: now that i have arrived at the solution it makes sense that $v(t)=v_0e^\frac{-bt}{m}$and it would be distributed sinusoidally between the x and y components of the velocity.But for that you would have to know that angular velocity is a constant and equal to$\frac{qB}{m}$ but that is hard to intuitively understand because there is  a torque on the mass due to the viscous force.I still dnt understand how angular velocity is constant.

Comment: That's easy. $\mathbf{\tau}=\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{F}$ , both forces are perpendicular.

Comment: the viscous force is perpendicular to the position vector assuming the centre of circular motion to be the origin, so there is torqe acting on the system

Comment: i get that torque due to magnetic field is 0 but what about torque due to viscous force

Comment: Can you post this problem as a different problem and put your work on the problem that leads you to this conclusion. As I don't know whether you expressions are right or wrong. I need to cross-check.

Comment: sure can I do it tomorrow its late at night here, ill do as soon as I wake  up.Thanks a lot for your help couldn't have done it without it!